# Is there a limit on the maximal number of consecutive threads a process can create?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, process

I have a program that is supposed to work for several weeks, and it constantly and frequently spawns threads. However there's no more than 10-15 threads running simultaneously at every moment. Can I run out of threads and get some UB/error at some point? For the record, the frequency of threads-spawning is about 1 thread/sec and above.

The question arose from a strange incident I encountered today. I have a script in Python that runs other program in C++:

```
def f():
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    while True:
        if p.poll() is not None:
            exit(0)
        time.sleep(1)

def g():

    run_bot_thread = self.create_and_start_thread(f)

    run_bot_thread.join()

while True:
    g()
    print('Sleep')
    time.sleep(1 * 60 * 60)
```

Usually if some error occurs in `cmd` part the script just exits, but now it looks like the same moment process ended, the thread also broke down and joined immediately, so I got surprising "Sleep" message on my screen.

Comment: You have multiple unrelated questions on your text: 1. failure to creating threads would give an error ? 2. why does the thread terminate when Popen fails. Please clarify in a more clear and single scoped question.

Comment: See [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The little code you did post doesn't correspond at all to your problem description. As an aside, why don't you just call `p.wait()` in function `f` and forget about looping? And why is that function calling `exit()` Instead of just returning or breaking out of the loop? And what is `cmd` that you reference?